# Has anyone got a solution for the problem <asp:treeview /> != <ul><li></li></ul>

Tags: html, treeview, rendering

I'm using the [`asp:TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) and would really rather just output it to a standard nested `<HTML>` list using `<ul>` and `<li>`, at the moment it produces some pretty ugly code using `<div>`s and `<table>`s.

Has anyone got a decent workaround?

I'm using `<asp:XmlDataSource>` to populate the `TreeView`

This [explains the current situation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=102232) very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ever looked at [CSS-Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/TreeView.aspx)? They should be doing what you are looking for.

Comment: And if it doesn't you can modify them.